# Visual Studio 2017 removing spaces before function parantheses in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, eslint

Like mentioned in the topic my Visual Studio keeps removing spaces before function parantheses in JavaScript files. The problem is that EsLint wants me to put in spaces there but everytime I save the file the spaces get removed.

I know that there are some options you can use for formatting JavaScript code but I think they are set properly.

[image: Visual Studio JavaScript Formatting Options]

Strange thing is that when I'm in debugging mode the removing of the spaces doesn't happen.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem: A possible workaround is to add ': function' after the function name. My VisualStudio then does not remove the space and eslint is happy.